# Take a picture from microsoft lifecams

Tags: c#, .net, photo

what is a simplest way i can use to take a picture from microsoft lifecams in c# windows application?

Answer (score 1):

I'd say it's the exact same as taking a picture with any other cam.

Check [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/wiascriptingdotnet.aspx) Code Project page for a detailed example:

> This sample shows how to use Windows XP Windows Image Acquisition
>   (WIA) Scripting with .NET and C#. It
>   is useful for integrating with
>   scanners, digital cameras, webcams and
>   still-video.
>
> Note, this article doesn't save you from reading the detailed WIA
>   documentation!

Answer (score 1):

It also appears that WIA for Windows 7 does NOT allow for accessing webcams.